# Remove unwanted space between thead and border

Tags: css, printing, css-tables

I want to remove space between thead top and tfoot bottom space marked as red in image.This space is showing when print browser page.

[image]

also I put my print css:

```
@media print{
    table { page-break-after:auto;border:1px solid #000;border-spacing: 1cm 1cm;border-collapse: separate;
            }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid;}
    td    { page-break-inside:auto;}
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-header-group }

    .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
      min-height: 20px;
    }
    tr.box td.inner_cell{width:6cm;height:3cm;border:none !important;}

    tr.box td.inner_cell_border{border:#3a3a3a 2px solid !important}

    tr td.sub_hdn_inner{font-weight:500;font-size:20px;background-color:#000;color:#fff;text-align:center;
                        border-top:1cm solid #fff !important;border-bottom:1cm solid #fff !important;
                        border-left:none;border-right:none;}
    tr td.extra_hdn_inner{font-weight:500;font-size:20px;text-align:center;
                        border-top:1cm solid #fff !important;border-bottom:1cm solid #fff !important;
                        border-left:none;border-right:none;}                    

    thead .sub_hdn{background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:none;padding:0.5cm;}
    tfoot .sub_hdn{background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:none;padding:0.5cm}
}

@page { 
    size: 64cm 49cm;
};
```

Comment: that space is because of your `border-spacing` property, adjust that.

Comment: yes i understand that...can we remove from thead top and tfoot bottom only?

Comment: yes you can, use it like this `border-spacing: 1cm 0cm;`!

Comment: The first value in `border-spacing` defines spacing for left and right and the second one is for top and bottom.